# Ruby on Rails: uninitialized constant, NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I am trying to solve a name error in a RAILS application. I am working on an interface which consists in a map with tiles associated to a certain number of projects.

I have the following models: `area.rb`

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :map_file_name, :tile_file_name, :alt, ...

  has_many :species
  has_many :maps

end
```

`map.rb`,

```
class Map < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :alt, :file_name, :detail, :area_id

  belongs_to :area
end
```

and `specie.rb`

```
class Specie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :area_id, :author_id, :name, :pwclass, :pwfamily, :txtlandscape, :txtpod, :map

  has_one :author
  belongs_to :area

end
```

When I try to call the resource in IRB or in a view I get the name error output. I changed `specie` to `field` and `species` to `fields`, and it works with the same configuration.

I checked and Ruby pluralises `specie` correctly to `species`.

How can I get `specie` to work?

UPDATE : backtrace

```
Started GET "/projects/show/1" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Mar 23 13:02:07 +0100 2018
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mArea Load (1.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 'areas'.* FROM 'areas' WHERE 'areas'.'id' = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "1"]]
  [1m[35mMap Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT 'maps'.* FROM 'maps' WHERE 'maps'.'area_id' = 1
  Rendered projects/show.html.erb (28.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 108ms

ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Area::Species):
    28:         end %>
    29: <% else %>
    30: <% end %>
    31: <% for specie in @area.species %>
    32: <div class="speciesmap">
    33:   <div id="tile_menu">
    34:     <a onclick="ArticleRequest('/article/show/area-07.html', 'ATLAS-06');"><img src="images/MAP/GUADALQUIVIR_MAP-BUTTONS-TILE-specie.svg" onMouseOver="this.src='images/MAP/estuario_area_136x85px-blck.svg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/MAP/GUADALQUIVIR_MAP-BUTTONS-TILE-specie.svg'" alt="Specie"></a>
  app/views/projects/show.html.erb:31:in '_app_views_projects_show_html_erb__1608931551_2294133420'
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:22:in `show'


  Rendered /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@ccc/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@ccc/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@ccc/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (40.4ms)
```

Comment: can you please post backtrace of error...

Comment: When you say you're using IRB, do you mean the Rails console? If not, your classes won't be available. Make sure you're using `rails console` as your entrypoint.

Comment: I tried both: IRB and rails console.

Comment: I found a solution by chance: I added `, :class_name => "Specie"` to the `area` model. I will add the backtrace and the solution. Do you know why the happened?

Comment: `species` is actually the same in both singular and plural. "Because the royal antelope is so small, the bottle’s nipple had to be specially designed for this species."

Comment: Rails will pluralise "specie correctly to species." because it adds an `s` to words it does not know how to inflect. You either need to change the model class name to `Species` or add an inflection that will make grammar nazis everywhere shudder in horror.

Comment: @max Ah I see: spe‧cie /ˈspiːʃiː-ʃiː, -siː/ noun [uncountable]
money in the form of coins, not bank notes.

Comment: @max Is there any problem with using model classes which do not have a plural form? Or should I use always a name which has singular and plural forms?

Comment: I don't think so, rails can handle inflecting "species" properly as well as a bunch of uncountable nouns so besides a bit of developer confusion I cant really see any problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167417/discussion-between-seju-and-max).

Answer (score 1):

Update the relation in your Area class to:

```
    has_many :species, :class_name => 'Specie'
```

Then `@area.species` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

As @max highlighted in the comments. The problem here is that species "is the same in both singular and plural".

The two solutions are either to use species as the model name or to declare a class name of "specie" in the related models.

I tried both, both are working. In the end I opted for @max's advice.